# refactor c++ auto loops to use begin, end, operator++

Tags: c++, for-loop, auto

Is there any way to refactor this:

```
for (auto it: container) { ... }
```

Into what it actually represents:

```
for (auto it=container.begin(); it != container.end(); ++it) { ... }
```

Since under the hood this is what happens, I wonder if there's a way to translate the former style to the latter

```
#include <iostream>
struct SomeClass {
    int x[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int *begin() { return x+1; }
    int *end()   { return x+4; }
};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SomeClass c;
    for (auto it: c) { std::cout << it << "\n"; }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `begin` should return `x` and `end` `x+5`, i.e. first element and one past the last element. But for arrays you can use `std::begin(x)` and `std::end(x)`. BTW, you would also like to add the `const` versions.

Comment: You just showed an example of such a translation, so why are you wondering whether it's possible?

Comment: `it` is a wrong name in `for (auto it: container)`. `it` is not an `iterator`, but an element/item of the container.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm looking for an automatic code refactor

Comment: @rturrado I deliberately put arbitrary values for begin and end to emphasize that they are completely user-controlled. Maybe `1` and `4` aren't the best choices though ...

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Then you ask for an automated tool, not about whether it's possible. (And then you get the question closed since asking for tools is off-topic.)

Comment: ^That. And also, why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: Although it's not hard to do by hand, why would you want to do that?    The "what it actually represents" form is more verbose and (arguably) less clear or maintainable than the range-based loop.    It can't see that your justification is that you want to support older C++ standards, since `auto` for type deduction and range-based for loops were both standardised at exactly the same time (in the 2011 standard)  i..e there is no C++ standard that supports one form and not the other.

Comment: @Peter the context is source-level analysis, and for that we need to "peel-off" as much "syntactic sugar" as possible

Comment: Language features being documented as "equivalent" are not "syntactic sugar". A range for loop is it's own thing. Or do you want to describe the `for` [in terms of `while`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for), and describe that [in terms of `goto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while)?

Comment: So, somehow one form of `for` loop is syntactic sugar, and the other is not?   As far as I'm concerned they both are.

Answer (score 1):

There is, you can do re-engineering like this in clang-tidy, by writing your own plug-in.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/exploring-clang-tooling-part-1-extending-clang-tidy/

Be aware this is a chunk of work, and you will need a bit of a beast of a machine to compile on. Specifically one with a lot of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

You can check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for to apply the transformation manually.

[Cppinsight](https://cppinsights.io/) is a tool that can expand your code to the equivalent iterator based loop.

Note however, that cppinsight produces a representation of the code that is internal to the compiler. It is not necessarily code that you should write yourself. In particular, names with two leading underscores are reserved and may not be used.

```
#include <iostream>
struct SomeClass
{
  int x[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  inline int * begin()
  {
    return this->x + 1;
  }
  
  inline int * end()
  {
    return this->x + 4;
  }
  
  // inline constexpr SomeClass() noexcept = default;
};


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  SomeClass c = SomeClass();
  {
    SomeClass & __range1 = c;
    int * __begin1 = __range1.begin();
    int * __end1 = __range1.end();
    for(; __begin1 != __end1; ++__begin1) {
      int it = *__begin1;
      std::operator<<(std::cout.operator<<(it), "\n");
    }
    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem with this solution (presumably the output from cppinsight) is that identifiers with two leading underscores followed by a lower case letter are reserved in the global namespace.   So the code as shown has undefined behaviour  (albeit, most likely only problematical if the compiler/standard library uses such identifiers, but auditing every compiler to check if that's the case is more effort than avoiding such identifiers).

Comment: @Peter thanks. Added a note. Actually I first wanted to post a comment only, but I don't know how to get a link to the code on cppinsight

Answer (score 0):

The start address of an array is the name of the array.

And `end()` points to the next part of the last element in the array.
So, `begin() {return x;}` and `end() {return x+5;}`.

You can check this site:
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/begin/
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/end/

[Graphical view of an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N6fy.png)